# jQuery animate method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code, I think code is fine without errors but still couldn't able to get the animation for 'div' tag. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("button").click(function() {
        $("div").animate({
          left: '450px'
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button>Start Animation</button>
  <p>A simple animation example:</p>
  <div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you load your page locally? Does the address bar in the browser have `file:///` at the beginning?

Comment: I placed your code in a snippet. As you can now see, it works absolutely fine. Please check for errors in the console.

Comment: @t.niese Yes, also as GhitaB stated I replaced my src with 'https' and it worked.

Comment: Thank you for the edit @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: @GhitaB Done, sry for the delay I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: No problem. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should use `src="//..."` if the resources are served with `http` or `https`, but the `//` will not work if you load the page locally using the `file:///` protocol

Replace 
`src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"`

with
`src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"`

Comment: You're assuming the OP is not using `https`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Isn't it a problem if the the file is loaded locally with the `file:///` protocol.

Comment: Thank you GhitaB, working like a charm. Can you please let me know why it is so important to have 'https' instead 'http'.

Comment: @t.niese you're correct. I think this answer could have saved some downvotes if GhitaB had explained why this is a solution more clearly.

Comment: @NaveenAkula in general you should use `src="//` if the resources are served with `http` and `https`, but the `//` will not work if you load the page locally using the `file:///` protocol.

Comment: @NaveenAkula I just tried on my computer your code I tried to give you a quick answer... With F12 I saw there is an error and I fixed it. I think you can use `http`, too. Can you accept the answer, please? :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly valid and runs; you can check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/on1jvjjj/). However I highly recommend using a specific selector for you jQuery objects especially when doing an operation such as animation.

```
<button>Start Animation</button>
<p>A simple animation example:</p>
<div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;"></div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("div").animate({
      left: '450px'
    });
  });
});
</script>
```